# ¿Porque me sale este error?

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pedidos.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `pedidos` where `pedidos`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], a tu pregunta le hacen falta detalles

Comment: Te fijaste que esté bien escrito el nombre de la columna?

Comment: ¿Tu base de datos es recien creada o ya existia?

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/361490/edit) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega esta propiedad a tu modelo `Pedidos`

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te esta diciendo que no se encuentra la columna `deleted_at` de la tabla `pedidos` verifica que este bien escrito.